# Is it possible to use CocoaPods through Nexus repository?

Tags: ios, maven, cocoapods, nexus, artifactory

In my company we do not have open internet access, so to develop the applications that depends of many dependences using a corporative Nexus.

In this Nexus we have mavencentral, jcenter, npmjs and others repository proxies. But we are starting to developing for iOS, and we want to use CocoaPods, but, first of all I have to know if is there some way to use CocoaPods through Nexus.

Some one knows how to do it?

> Artifactory has a issue to implement this feature.
>   https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5385

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now `Nexus` doesn't support `CocoaPods`:
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9733
And `Artifactory` does (since v.4.5):
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+4.5

More information according different repositories features could be found on this feature matrix: http://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/

It's a bit outdated, but I'm currently working on its updating.

Answer (score 5):

Nexus 3.19.0 now supporting Cocoapods and Conda:

https://blog.sonatype.com/cocoapods-conda-in-nexus-repository

More detailed set up here: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/cocoapods-repositories

Answer (score 2):

As of 7/2/2015,

Nexus doesn't have support yet for Cocoapods.
They might consider adding it for Nexus 3 eventually if there is enough demand.
-> from their tech support.

I'm looking for a workaround for it..

Answer (score 0):

Sonatype Nexus 3 added Cocoapods support from NXRM 3.19.0